# A proverb/idiom synonymous to "changing horses in the midstream"

Tags: idioms, proverbs

Is there a synonym to the idiom in the title which uses the simile of changing table cloth during the meal/dinner and if so, how is it properly worded?

Heard it in a US movie dubbed in my native language but couldn't trace its English origin in Google and in the movie's transcript.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The saying "changing table cloth during the meal/dinner" does not exist as a "saying" in English. "Changing horses in midstream", and related variations, are quite common:

> “I think that there’ll be a lot of upset kids that didn’t take it ’cause it wasn’t for credit ’cause we said it was not going to be … and I just don’t feel like we should change horses in the river.” (Mt. Vernon Register-News)

At https://grammarist.com/phrase/dont-change-horses-in-midstream/ the saying "changing horses in midstream" is plausibly credited to  Abraham Lincoln:"

> [Abraham Lincoln] used the phrase "no time to swap horses" when talking about the presidential election during the Civil War, as well as talking about replacing his generals. It is assumed that the term "don’t change horses in midstream" is derived from a popular joke published in 1840, in which a man crossing a stream with his horse and colt falls into the water. He grabs the colt’s tail and lets it drag him from the water, but before making it to the other side of the water the colt grows tired. When bystanders advise him to grab the mare’s tail instead, the man says, “This is no time to swap horses.”

Comment: I didn't know Lincoln coind the phrase. I had always heard it in relation to Roosevelt, who according to this article, "FDR revived in 1944, when he urged voters, "Don't change horses in midstream." https://www.baltimoresun.com/maryland/bs-md-backstory-presidents-expressions-20130425-story.html

Comment: @mtugglet Lincoln did not coin it - he said "no time to swap horses". The origin of the "midstream" version seems to have been a popular joke.

Comment: thank you, the quest continues